# Split data from columns in one table to multiple rows in another

Tags: sql

I have table as below. If I need to create another table as shown in the output, how can I do it?

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
    (JobID int, isAllowType1 bit, value1 int, isAllowType2 bit, value2 int)
;

INSERT INTO TestTable
    (JobID, isAllowType1, value1, isAllowType2, value2)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 11, 0, 111),
    (2, 0, 22, 1, 222),
    (3, 1, 33, 0, 333)
;
```

--output

```
JOBID  isAllow   Value        Type
    1        1      11        Type1
    1        0      111       Type2
    2        0      22        Type1
    2        1      222       Type2
    3        1      33        Type1
    3        0      333       Type2
```

Comment: Is there a need for another table? Can't you use a view or a stored procedure?

Comment: I am refactoring a table which has so many columns like isAllow1, isAllow2, isAllow3 with various different values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the query the type1 and type2 records separately, and use the `union all` operator to combine the results:

```
SELECT jobid, isAllowType1 AS isAllow, value1 AS value, 'Type1' AS type
FROM   testtable
UNION ALL
SELECT jobid, isAllowType1 AS isAllow, value1 AS value, 'Type2' AS type
FROM   testtable
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mureinik's answer, you can create a new table using result of a `UNION ALL` like so:

```
select *
into new_table
from (
    select JobID,
        isAllowType1 isAllowType,
        value1 value,
        'Type1' Type
    from TestTable

    union all

    select JobID,
        isAllowType2,
        value2,
        'Type2'
    from TestTable
    ) t
```